# Jenkins can't find npm but it can find npm.cmd - Windows 10

Tags: windows, jenkins, npm, path, cygwin

I am running into a new problem with the NPM path on a Windows 10 VM.

Node.js and NPM are setup via NVM for Windows.

We are using Cygwin.

After I connect the VM to Jenkins via Swarm, I try and run a simple `npm --version` command and it says NPM can't be found.

However if I run `npm.cmd --version` it prints `6.14.12`

Also if I run `which npm` it returns `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm`

But then `npm --version` fails.

[image]

All of these commands work on the VM when I remote into it but when I connect it to Jenkins it fails in the Jenkins script console and in builds.

What am I not understanding? Why, in Jenkins, does `NPM` fail but `NPM.cmd` work?

We are using Windows, Redhat, and MacOS VMs in our multibranch pipeline so the commands have to be OS independent.

Comment: If the file is called `npm.cmd`, why do you then invoke it just by `npm`?